# Heroku Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, heroku

sorry if this is a duplicate. I couldn't find answer anywhere.

I'm giving Heroku a try. I'm trying to deploy a demo Java Spring Boot REST API to it and I'm not having any luck.

You can view my pom.xml here. And the various things I tried in the git log if you're interested. Otherwise my pom.xml is below. I've got heroku setup to automatically deploy from this repository branch.

https://github.com/tomdemay/UserMgmtPortal/blob/master/user-mgmt-backend/pom.xml

I have no problems building or running in my environment. This pom file was generated by the spring initializer about 2 weeks ago.

```
   [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :dependency
   [INFO] Compiling 11 source files with javac [debug release 17] to target/classes
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [INFO] Total time:  8.845 s
   [INFO] Finished at: 2023-07-22T03:08:15Z
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) on project user-mgmt-backend: Fatal error compiling: invalid flag: --release -> [Help 1]
   [ERROR]
```

my POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.tomdemay.pro
    </groupId>
    <artifactId>user-mgmt-backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>user-mgmt-backend</name>
    <description>User Management Portal Backend</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.0-M9</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a system.properties file at the **root** of your project with this line

```
java.runtime.version=17
```

See https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2268